# loop through output of find command in here documents after sudo

Tags: shell, unix, loops, find

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u rei_sh -H -s <<-EOM

echo "hi"

for i in $(find -name *.properties)

do

echo "ivalue is \$i"

done

exit

EOM
```

I am using the above piece of code.

When I run the code only "hi" gets printed.

but if I use "for i in one two" the following gets printed

```
ivalue is one
ivalue is two.
```

Why can't I loop through the output of find command inside a here document?

Comment: Note that `<<` works just as well as `<<-` here, since the HEREDOC is never seen by human eyes.  (And since there is no indentation, they are exactly identical).

Answer (score 3):

Because the `$(...)` is run before the `sudo` kicks in...you need to quote the `EOM`:

```
sudo -u rei_sh -H -s <<-'EOM'
    echo "hi"
    for i in $(find -name *.properties)
    do
        echo "ivalue is $i"
    done
EOM
```

The `exit` is redundant.  With the quotes around the `EOM`, you also don't need to escape the `$` in the `echo` command.  You could alternatively have escaped the `$` before the `$(...)` to prevent the pre-`sudo` shell from executing the command.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan.i tried with 'EOM'.still the same result.Just "hi" gets printed.Please advice. Before posting the question here,I tried escaping the $ before the $(...).That didnt work too.

Comment: Oh, fiddlesticks!  The `find` command should be fixed. `find . -name '*.properties'` or thereabouts, but you should be getting error messages from it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

process substitution & variable expansion happens before heredocs are processed.

Try escaping the $ signs & glob (*).